# Linear combination resulting from a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function., $0=w_1,\cdots,w_m$ be distinct complex numbers and $n$ be a positive integer. Denote by $r$ a real greater than $\max_{1\le j\le m}|w_j|$ and  by $\mathcal C$ be the circle of center $0$ and radius $r$.
I want to show that
$$R(z)=\int_{\mathcal C}\frac{f(xz)}{\prod_{j=1}^m(x-w_j)^n}\mathrm d x$$
can be expressed in the form $R(z)=\sum_{i=1}^mP_i(z)f(w_iz)$,
where $P_i$ are polynomials of degree $<n$. Moreover $R$ has a zero of order a least $m(n-1)+1$ at $0$. Any answer will be welcome.

Comment: Why do u think this is true? Try the case $m=1, f(0)=0, n=3, f''(0) \ne 0$

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your comment before. You are right. I know that it is true for the exponential function, so I thought it could easily be generalized. But I was wrong unfortunately.